# Вывод многомерного ассоциативного массива php

Tags: php

формучане !:)Пол дня бью и никак не получается вывести массив в виде таблицы:

```
Array
(
  [poroda0] => Array
    (
        [value] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [del_0] => 0
                        [Step_0] => 4
                        [drov_0] => 0
                        [vis1_0] => 0
                        [vis2_0] => 0
                        [vis3_0] => 0
                        [poldel_0] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [del_1] => 0
                        [Step_1] => 6
                        [drov_1] => 0
                        [vis1_1] => 0
                        [vis2_1] => 0
                        [vis3_1] => 0
                        [poldel_1] => 0
                    )
                //=========================

                [58] => Array
                    (
                        [del_58] => 0
                        [Step_58] => 120
                        [drov_58] => 0
                        [vis1_58] => 0
                        [vis2_58] => 0
                        [vis3_58] => 0
                        [poldel_58] => 0
                    )

            )

        [name_0] => sosna
    )

[poroda1] => Array
    (
        [value] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [del_59] => 0
                        [Step_59] => 4
                        [drov_59] => 0
                        [vis1_59] => 0
                        [vis2_59] => 0
                        [vis3_59] => 0
                        [poldel_59] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [del_60] => 0
                        [Step_60] => 6
                        [drov_60] => 0
                        [vis1_60] => 0
                        [vis2_60] => 0
                        [vis3_60] => 0
                        [poldel_60] => 0
                    )
                //===============================


                [58] => Array
                    (
                        [del_117] => 0
                        [Step_117] => 120
                        [drov_117] => 0
                        [vis1_117] => 0
                        [vis2_117] => 0
                        [vis3_117] => 0
                        [poldel_117] => 0
                    )

            )

        [name_1] => sosna
    )

)
```

[poroda0] - первая таблица, [poroda1] - вторая таблица и т.д. У породы есть название [name_0], [name_1] и значения [value], где одна строка таблицы

```
    [0] => Array
      (
         [del_0] => 0
         [Step_0] => 4
         [drov_0] => 0
         [vis1_0] => 0
         [vis2_0] => 0
         [vis3_0] => 0
         [poldel_0] => 0
      )
```

Пробовал через вложенные foreach и как-то не получилось.
Пожалуйста, помогите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = array(...);
foreach ($data as $tablekey => $table) {
  $tableidx = substr($tablekey, 6);
  echo $table['name_' . $tableIdx];
  echo '<table>';
  foreach ($table['value'] as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($row as $val) {
      echo '<td>';
      echo $val;
      echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь! :)